# How to find type definition file for xss-clean npm library

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I just started to learn typescript and just started converting my nodejs/express application to typescript.
I have successfully got all types for the library using npm i @types/some-lib
only library, I can't find was npm i @types/xss-clean
where to find this library

```
import xss from 'xss-clean' //getting type definition error
app.use(xss())
```

Comment: It doesn't exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the library does not have many TypeScript users, chances are that no published types exist. In that case you can add your own to whatever degree of detail you wish.

You can create a type definition file, e.g. `xss-clean.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'xss-clean'
{
  const value: Function;

  export default value;
}
```

[[More on declaration files]](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html)

Comment: i got little idea through search to put this file inside node_modules/@types 
but how can i get back when i exclude node_modules and use "npm i" in other environment

Comment: `node_module/@types` is for types installed via npm, place custom declarations in e.g. a `types` folder inside your project source code, not in `node_modules`. If the types are not found automatically you can adjust the [`typeRoots`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots) in the `tsconfig.json` to point to the directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this page](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/) to look up if a package has types or not. `xss-clean` does not seem to have any types yet, so you would have to declare them by yourself.

More info on that [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html).